# scrapy can't handle "<" character

Tags: scrapy, lxml, parsel

I'm trying to extract text containing "<" (lower than character). On my localhost everything works fine, on the server however the text after and including "<" gets truncated.

```
1) hipoksemia tętnicza (PaO<sub>2</sub>/FiO<sub>2</sub> < 300 )
```

so I receive:

```
1) hipoksemia t\u0119tnicza (PaO<sub>2</sub>/FiO<sub>2</sub>
```

There is no problem with scraping > character. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you say which type of systems you are using on localhost/remote? Which OS, Shell, Python Version

Answer (score 0):

`<` is invalid HTML. It should be `&lt;`.

Scrapy uses [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/) to parse XML/HTML responses. Parsel uses [lxml](https://lxml.de/) to parse XML/HTML documents. lxml does not handle broken HTML as well as web browsers and other parsers do.

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/126) for Parsel to handle these scenarios. It will probably require supporting an alternative to lxml in Parsel, which is not trivial to implement, so it may take a while before that issue is solved.